# How can I backup my Debian VPS to my local Windows Server?

Tags: windows, networking, backup, internet, debian

I've just set up my VPS (Debian 6) and configured everything nicely and I now want to get a backup in place. I have a Windows 2008 server running at home that I would like to use if possible. Is there any software that people could recommend that would allow me to backup my VPS to my Windows server over the net?

Comment: What are you looking to back up? Home directories and /etc?

Comment: Home directories, /etc and MySQL databases at the minimum. I would rather a way to backup the whole OS as it only takes up just over 1GB.

Answer (score 0):

Well in this case, the classic file copy backup option, using a scp client such as winscp or [cyberduck](http://cyberduck.ch/) might be a good idea - you would start with a installed system with a VPS anyway, so simply copying over files such as the contents of your /home,/var and /etc directories would be a good enough backup method.

Comment: I agree with this approach and was going to suggest it. You're not going to be able to get a full system image unless your VPS host supports it. Your best bet is to backup the folders and files suggested above.